# MessagingStyle Not Displaying "You" Properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

New to Android development and playing with the latest `MessagingStyle` code. Messages from You are being displayed with the correct icon, but, for the name, I'm expecting You instead of the recipient's name, just like the built-in Messages app. Not sure if this is something Kotlin related or not.

Any thoughts appreciated - `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are both 28.

An example of what I’m seeing is:

[image]

Notification methods and related (less important code removed):

```
fun notifyTest(context: Context, upcoming: UpcomingDetail, top3Sent: List<String>?) {
    //...

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    when (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        in 1..27 -> {
            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
                notify(upcoming.id.toInt(), legacyNotificationBuilder(
                        context,
                        upcoming,
                        noteIntent,
                        contentPending,
                        disablePending,
                        deletePending,
                        postponePending,
                        top3Sent
                ).build())
            }
        }
        else -> context.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
                .notify(upcoming.id.toInt(), notificationBuilder(
                        context,
                        upcoming,
                        noteIntent,
                        contentPending,
                        disablePending,
                        deletePending,
                        postponePending,
                        top3Sent
                ).build())
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private fun notificationBuilder(
        context: Context,
        upcoming: UpcomingDetail,
        noteIntent: Intent,
        contentPending: PendingIntent,
        deletePending: PendingIntent,
        disablePending: PendingIntent,
        postponePending: PendingIntent,
        top3Sent: List<String>?
): Notification.Builder {
    val recipient: android.app.Person = android.app.Person.Builder().setName("Darren").setImportant(true).build()
    val you: android.app.Person? = null

    val messageStyle = Notification.MessagingStyle(recipient)
    messageStyle.addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle.Message("What's up?", Instant.now().minusSeconds(5 * 60).toEpochMilli(), recipient))
    messageStyle.addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle.Message("Doing great!", Instant.now().toEpochMilli(), you))

    //...

    return Notification.Builder(context, "Input").apply {
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
        style = messageStyle
        setAutoCancel(true)
        setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
        setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.secondaryDarkColor))
        setContentIntent(contentPending)
        setDeleteIntent(deletePending)
        setGroup("notifications")
        setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
        addAction(inputAction)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do 2 things:

1. Pass a You-person to `Notification.MessagingStyle` constructor, not a recipient.
2. Pass a null to every `Notification.MessagingStyle.Message` from You-person. There is minor issue in Kotlin with that due to new API because it has a type `Person`, not `Person?`.

I just checked this code, it works like you want to:

```
val recipient: Person = Person.Builder().setName("Darren").build()
val you: Person = Person.Builder().setName("You").build()
val nullPerson: Person? = null

val messageStyle = Notification.MessagingStyle(you) // pass you-person here
messageStyle.addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle.Message("What's up?", timestamp1, recipient))
messageStyle.addMessage(Notification.MessagingStyle.Message("Doing great!", timestamp2, nullPerson)) // pass to null for a message to display `You`
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the documentation is not clear at all, cheers!